# Extend UI of an View

Tags: android, user-interface, view, extend, ondraw

I would like to extend the UI of AutoCompleteTextView. The Functionality is fine, all I need is to add an button to the right that looks like a drop-down button. Sadly AutoCompleteTextView has a 'natural' margin that I can't reduce to 0.

What can I do now?
Dose I have to overwrite onDraw() & onMeasure() to archive my goal (is there an easier way)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put both `AutoCompleteTextView` and button onto `FrameLayout`, add some extra margin right to `AutoCompleteTextView` to make `FrameLayout` slightly bigger, and align button to parent right. In fact, these 2 views will interfere, but for user they will appear one next to the other w/o any margin.
Another option could be to set custom background to `AutoCompleteTextView` (probably modified original one taken from Android source with removed margin).

Just remembered that you can supply negative margin. You can put both views onto `LinearLayout` and set left margin of button to `-5dp` for example. However, you will still have to supply custom marginless background for button.

Comment: Setting a custom background is the solution to my problem ('shape' in xml with several attributes).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `RelativeLayout` to put Button to the right of `AutoCompleteTextView`

[image]

**Sample**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
   <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/btn_close_pressed"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:id="@+id/myBtn"
></Button>
<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/myautocomplete"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:completionThreshold="1"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/myBtn"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```